# Image hosting site image downloader using requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I went about this the way I have because Selenium is slow and inconvenient (opens browser) and I was unable to find the `href` attribute in the link element using BeautifulSoup. Html included below. On the downside, this appears to only ever find 25 images.

```
#! python3

# Saves photos to file from flickr.com using specified search term

import bs4
import logging
import os
import re
import requests
import shutil
import sys
import time


def find_link(element):
    """Finds link using a regular expression"""

    link_regex = re.compile(r"//c\d+.staticflickr.com/\d+/\d+/\w+\.jpg")
    # dictionary of element attributes
    element_attr_dict = element.attrs

    # get list of element attribute values wherein image link lies   
    attr_list = [element_attr_dict[key] for key in element_attr_dict.keys()]
    attr_string = ""

    # link exists within a string list element
    for element in attr_list:
        if type(element) == str:
            attr_string += element
    match = link_regex.search(attr_string)
    if match:
        link = "https:" + match.group()
    else:
        link = None
    return link


def main():
    """Downloads specified type/number of 'flickr' images to folder

    Takes three command line arguments: "filename, search_term, number_
    images". Saves images to folder. Number of images saved based upon
    number requested by user or number found during search. Whichever is
    lower.

    Arguments:
    search_term   -- search image site using this term
    number_images -- maximum number of images to save to folder
    """

    try:
        search_term, number_images = sys.argv[1:]
        number_images = int(number_images)
    except ValueError:
        print("Something went wrong. Command line input must be of \
format: 'filename searchterm numberimages'")
        return

    links = []
    # make folder to store photos and name using search term
    html_path = r"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\2016Coding\AutomateBoring\11" + \
                r"-WebScraping\flickrhtml.txt"
    path = \
    r"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\2016Coding\AutomateBoring\11-WebScraping" + \
    r"\gimages\requests"
    folder_path = os.path.join(path, search_term)
    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path)

    print("Finding photos...")

    # get links to photos
    res = requests.get("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=" + search_term)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    found_elems = soup.select(".photo-list-photo-view")

    # incase number found images < requested
    number_save_images = min(number_images, len(found_elems))

    print("Found {} images".format(number_save_images))

    for found_elem in found_elems[:number_save_images]:
        link = find_link(found_elem)
        links.append(link)

    # write images to file
    print("Writing images to folder...")
    for image_link in links:
        basename = os.path.basename(image_link)
        save_file_name = os.path.join(folder_path, basename)
        res = requests.get(image_link)
        res.raise_for_status()

        with open(save_file_name, "wb") as f:
            for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
                f.write(chunk)

    print("Images saved at: {}".format(folder_path))
    print("*****Done*****")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PEP8 standard library import should be first.

Function `find_link(element)`:

1. The docstring of the function `find_link` should probably say something about the argument type.
2. Why is the argument element (and not `element_attributes`) when it looks like all you use is `element.attrs`?
3. The list comprehension could be written as: `attr_list = list(element_attr_dict.values())` 
   But, you don't need it at all. You can simply write `for element in attr_dict.values()`.

To summarize, you can delete most lines in the beginning. Instead start with

```
def find_link(element_attributes):
    link_regex = re.compile(r"//c\d+.staticflickr.com/\d+/\d+/\w+\.jpg")
    attr_string = ""
    for element in element_attributes.values():
        ...
```

As for the main function:

1. Investigate [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).
2. Use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) instead of `print`.
3. Split the main function to sub-functions. At least saving an image from a link should probably be one.
4. The for loop where you append a link to a list can be expressed as a list comprehension.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! I've sorted the list comprehension in the main function and I do use logging (removed it  before posting). All my print statements are deliberate. Eg whilst catching a value error, it's just a neater (imo) way of reminding myself about the format to use while at the command line. Let me if that isn't a legitimate use" I'll get on the rest tomorrow!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, your first answers looks good, enjoy your stay!

Comment: Argparse is great. It solves an problem I had with my own command line  method; optionals.

Answer (score 2):

Scraping is better than using Selenium, but you've still missed the easiest, most maintainable, and least likely to get yourself IP-banned way: [the Flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/).  There's [a search method](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) and [a method that returns URLs of the variously-sized versions of an image](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html).  And of course, there are [many](https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) [different](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-flickr) [wrappers](https://github.com/alexis-mignon/python-flickr-api) [already written](https://github.com/search?l=Python&langOverride=&q=flickr&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories) to make querying the API easy in Python.

Aside from that, the most obvious thing that stands out to me is the lack of any argument parsing.  kaidokuuppa already mentioned `argparse`, which is nice because it's in the standard library.  I personally prefer the approach of [docopt](http://docopt.org/) (Python implementation [here](https://github.com/docopt/docopt)), since it encourages writing good, useful help messages.

Somewhat still on that subject, I favor doing the command-line parsing separately from the rest of your `main()`; this allows someone else (perhaps you!) who wants to use that function as a library to import it and pass the appropriate parameters in.

Comment: Appreciate it! This was just a challenge in a beginners book and so I was operating with a very low level of scraping knowledge but I will certainly investigate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I've covered everything you guys suggested, with the exception of the flickr api, and that it's been implemented correctly(unsure regarding argparse; I completed only a short tutorial). Revised code:

```
#! python3

# Saves photos to file from flickr.com using specified search term

import argparse
import logging
import os
import re
import shutil
import sys
import time
import bs4
import requests


def handle_input():
    """Parses user input and provides guidance as to correct input format""" 

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("search_term",
                        help="The term to use in the 'flickr' search")
    parser.add_argument("number_images", type=int,
                        help="The maximum number of images to save to folder.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args.search_term, args.number_images


def find_link(element_attr_dict):
    """Finds link using a regular expression

    Arguments:
    element -- html element containing a link to image src within its
               attribute value
    """

    link_regex = re.compile(r"//c\d+.staticflickr.com/\d+/\d+/\w+\.jpg")

    # link resides within a string. Get all string dict values and search
    attr_string = ""
    for value in element_attr_dict.values():
        if type(value) == str:
            attr_string += value
    match = link_regex.search(attr_string)

    if match:
        link = "https:" + match.group()
    else:
        link = None
    return link


def save_images(link_list, path):
    """Saves images to 'path' using the basename of each link as filename

    link_list -- a list of src links which are used to download images
    path      -- the absolute path in which to save the images
    """

    print("Writing images to folder...")
    for image_link in link_list:
        basename = os.path.basename(image_link)
        save_file_name = os.path.join(path, basename)
        res = requests.get(image_link)
        res.raise_for_status()

        with open(save_file_name, "wb") as f:
            for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
                f.write(chunk)
    print("Images saved at: {}".format(path))


def main():
    """Downloads specified type/number of 'flickr' images to folder

    Takes three command line arguments: "filename, search_term, number_
    images". Saves images to folder. Number of images saved based upon
    number requested by user or number found during search. Whichever is
    lower.

    Arguments:
    search_term   -- search image site using this term
    number_images -- maximum number of images to save to folder
    """


    search_term, number_images = handle_input()

    links = []
    # make folder to store photos and name using search term
    path = \
    r"C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\2016Coding\AutomateBoring\11-WebScraping" + \
    r"\gimages\requests"
    folder_path = os.path.join(path, search_term)
    if os.path.exists(folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path)

    print("Finding photos...")

    # get links to photos
    res = requests.get("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=" + search_term)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    found_elems = soup.select(".photo-list-photo-view")

    # incase number found images < requested
    number_save_images = min(number_images, len(found_elems))

    print("Found {} images".format(number_save_images))

    links = [find_link(found_elem.attrs) for found_elem in \
             found_elems[:number_save_images]]

    # save images to folder
    save_images(links, folder_path)

    print("*****Done*****")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```